# how to enable NPAPI plugin in chrome in Ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, npapi

As title,

Does anyone knows how to enable the npapi plugin in chrome version 38??

I google it, but I still could not get a answer.

Comment: You cannot enable something that does not exist. The Linux port of Chromium does not support NPAPI.

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your respond.

Comment: Any reason that's not posted as an answer? It is the answer to the question.

Comment: sorry, please tell me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 35 NPAPI is no longer supported in Linux versions of Chrome and Chromium. In the Windows versions you can still enable it on the page: `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi`.